# how to get quickpay payment id after successful payment using Quickpay Form

Tags: payment-gateway, quickpay

I integrate Quickpay Payment gateway into my website with Quickpay Form [See The link](https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/payments/link/). But i am unable to get payment id after successful payment.

Please anyone help me how can i get the payment id, to save into my DB.

```
                      Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Section and edit your question accordingly. In cases like these, we expect you to fully provide us with code, not to only request and feature and hope somebody will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You use the callback or if you give your order an orderid you can use the quickpay api to call your payment on that and the API retrieves your payment id

`https://api.quickpay.net/payments?order_id=(your order id)`

Comment: Thank you for this.
It is actually in the docs, just had to look at the right endpoint:
https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/api/services/?scope=merchant#GET-payments---format-